# React Navigation I requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I just started my new project. After installing `react-navigation` and using it in my IOS app i got an error `Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig" was not found in the UIManager.`. I unable to find out what's the problem.

Here is My navigation code

```
import React from 'react';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import strings from '../Constants/Strings';
import {Home} from '../Screens';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default MainStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name={strings.navHome} component={Home} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import MainStack from './MainStack';

const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MainStack />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default Routes;
```

Anyone can tell me what's the probem? I never got error like this before

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using
**@react-navigation/native-stack**, you should install **react-native-screens** and **react-native-safe-area-context** too. I believe your error is because you don't have installed **react-native-screens**

Check the [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started)

Comment: @Thalia Aquino I have everything installed but still getting the issue

Comment: @Amjad if you are developing for iOS, have you run npx pod-install ios after install them?
You can try to delete node_modules, and install them again.

Answer (score 2):

I install `@react-navigation/native-stack` and `react-native-safe-area-context` and `react-native-screens`

but have same error

```
Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig" was not found in the UIManager
```

Answer (score 0):

Previously must have been installed.

```
@react-navigation/native-stack
react-native-safe-area-context
react-native-screens
```

Additionally, try clearing the cache and recompiling the app.

```
watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf node_modules
yarn cache clean && yarn
npx pod-install
yarn start --reset-cache
```

After that, you can try running the app with:

```
yarn run ios
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing the pods worked for me!!

```
npx pod-install
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if you using expo you must use build development because it need native libiraries ,if not try to rebuild